# Is it appropriate to tag an iframe audio player with itemprop audio?

Tags: soundcloud, schema.org

Schema.org's [example](http://schema.org/MusicRecording) for a music track shows a "play button" tagged as `itemprop="audio"` within the `itemprop="track"` element.

If I'm embedding an entire iframe from a service like soundcloud (but could be any service), is it appropriate to tag the iframe as the "audio"?

```
<article class="track" itemprop="track" itemscope 
  itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicRecording">
  <span itemprop="name">My Song</span>
  <meta itemprop="url" content="http://mysite.com/music">
  <iframe itemprop="audio" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/p..."></iframe>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is. 
As for me your use case matches *audio* property description:

> An embedded audio object.

One can say, that you embed audio via iframe.

Besides *audio* property is of type [AudioObject](http://schema.org/AudioObject)  which is broader than just link to a page.
Description of the type says

> An audio file.

But in fact this is more about audio object embedded to the page someway. Consider code example at that page where markup is done around flash player.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AudioObject">
  <span itemprop="name"><b>12oclock_girona.mp3</b></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var fo = new FlashObject("http://google.com/flash/preview-player.swf",
  "flashPlayer_719", "358", "16", "6", "#FFFFFF");fo.addVariable("url","http://media.freesound.org/data/0/previews/719__elmomo__12oclock_girona_preview.mp3");fo.addVariable("autostart", "0");fo.write("flashcontent_719");
</script>

<meta itemprop="encodingFormat" content="mp3" />
 <meta itemprop="contentURL" content="http://media.freesound.org/data/0/previews/719__elmomo__12oclock_girona_preview.mp3" />

<span class="description">
                <meta itemprop="duration" content="T0M15S" />
                <span itemprop="description">Recorded on a terrace of Girona a sunday morning</span>
</span>
</div>
```

Besides this type was derived (at least partly) from rNews. As it is said

> This class contains derivatives of IPTC rNews properties. rNews is a
>   data model of publishing metadata with serializations currently
>   available for RDFa as well as HTML5 Microdata. More information about
>   the IPTC and rNews can be found at rnews.org.

And in rNews the [goal](http://dev.iptc.org/rNews-10-Quick-Reference) of AudioObject is to mark

> audio ... object associated with an  Article.

and it doesn't matter, how (iframe, link, etc) it is done.

Comment: Nice.  Thanks for the thorough answer.